# python - Subprocess outputting empty string when shell=False

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I'm trying to run a script from a different directory and collect the output, using the `subprocess` module. For some reason I can only get the output using the `shell=True` syntax and not the `shell=False` syntax, which returns an empty string.

As a start, when in the command line I run:

`python ~/example/path/run.py -r arg1 -g arg2`

I get the output `124` in the command line.

In a different python script, in a completely different directory, I then run:

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.check_output('python /Users/user.name/example/path/run.py -r arg1 -g arg2', 
                shell = True)
```

Which returns the desired output `124`. However, I read `shell=True` should be avoided so instead I try:

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.check_output(['python',
                 'run.py',
                 '-r arg1',
                 '-g arg2'],
                cwd='/Users/user.name/example/path/')
```

which unfortunately outputs an empty string. I've tried several alternatives to this, all outputting an empty string:

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.check_output(['python',
                 '/Users/user.name/example/path/run.py',
                 '-r arg1',
                 '-g arg2'])

import subprocess as sp
sp.check_output(['python',
                 'run.py',
                 '-r arg1',
                 '-g arg2'],
                cwd='/Users/user.name/example/path/',
                stderr=sp.STDOUT)

import subprocess as sp
sp.check_output(['python',
                 'run.py',
                 '-r', 'arg1',
                 '-g', 'arg2'],
                cwd='/Users/user.name/example/path/',
                stderr=sp.STDOUT)
```

Apologies for not giving a reproducible example, as the problem seems to occur specifically for this command. For instance when I try the command `ls` it seems to work fine with both syntax options.

Comment: You need to really separate the arguments: `..., '-r', 'arg1', '-g', 'arg2',...`

Comment: Thanks for commeting; unfortunately that did not solve the problem as the output is still an empty string.

Comment: Can you please try to run some standard commands for reference? I just tried ``sp.check_output(['ls', '-la'])`` versus ``sp.check_output(' '.join(['ls', '-la']), shell=True)`` but they both give the same output.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi those two commands give the exact same output for me.